# Is it possible to open widgets.getsitecontrol.com/ javascript from azure bot v4?

Tags: node.js, azure, widget, botframework

I want to open widgets.getsitecontrol.com/ javascript page that I have implemented on my website. Whenever I type 'Help' inside my bot, the widget should open. Is it possible to open it? Thanks. I am using node js version. If it is possible, please provide me an approach to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how your widget functions, but when the user sends a 'help' message to the bot, you can send a back channel event to WebChat to trigger opening the widget. Take a look at the code snippets below.

**Bot Code - NodeJs**

When the bot receives a 'help' message from the user, the bot can send an event by sending an activity with the type set to 'event'. We can also give the outgoing activity a name attribute so we can send mutltiple types of events to WebChat. In this case, we are going to name the out going activity 'helpEvent'.

```
async onTurn(turnContext) {
    if(turnContext.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message) {
        if (turnContext.activity.text.toLowerCase() === 'help') {
            // Send Back Channel Help Event
            await turnContext.sendActivity({ type: 'event', name: 'helpEvent'});
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

**WebChat Custom Middleware**

In WebChat, we are going to create a custom middleware to check incoming activities. When we encounter an activity that has a name and type that we recognize, trigger your event on the webpage. In the example below, I just alerted the use that they asked for help, but here is where you launch your widget.

```
const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
    {},
    ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
          const { name, type } = action.payload.activity;

          if (type === 'event' && name === 'helpEvent') {
            // Activate Widget 
            alert("You asked for help.");
          }
        }
        return next(action);
    }
);

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
    store,
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

For more details on back channel events and creating a custom middleware in WebChat, checkout [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/11.customization-redux-actions) in the WebChat Repo.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @tdurnford. I have a problem with this script. I have my bot store History so now every time I refresh or go to another page. It goes in the if (type === 'event' && name === 'helpEvent') { } and perform the action. How do I prevent it from going in there unless someone type Help again. Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by storing the conversation history? It should only be executed when a help event is sent to Web Chat.

Comment: chatbot.connectionStatus$.subscribe(function (status) {                
      sessionStorage.setItem('conversationId',  chatbot.conversationId);
     });

Comment: This script store the ConversationId so when you refresh the page, the history conversation will restore but if I typed 'help' then refresh the page. It will always go in the  if (type === 'event' && name === 'helpEvent') { } and perform the action but I don't want that. How can I prevent it? I just want it to happen whenever the user type help.